# Is this correct? to prove the linearity of a function

Tags: analysis

Let $f: U \subset \mathbb{R}^{m} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be diferentiable in $U$ (open set), let $a \in U$ such that $[a,a+h] \in U$ and $|f'(x) - T| \leq M$ $\forall x \in (a,a+h)$ we know that $|f(a+h) - f(a) - T(v)| \leq M |v|$. $T$ is a linear transformation ordinary from $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Assume  that $f^{'}(x) \equiv T$. Show that $g_{a}(v) = f(a+v) - f(a)$ is linear function.

So if $f^{'}(x) \equiv T$ then exist a $x \in [a,a+h]$ such that $|f'(x) - T| = 0 \leq M$, then we can assume $M = 0$ and $|f(a+h) - f(a) - T(v)| \leq M |v|$ implies that $|g_{a}(v) - f^{'}(a)v| = 0$ therefore $g_{a}(v) = f^{'}(a)v$.

Comment: Are you assuming that $f'(x) = T$ on $U$? If so, then $\phi(v) = f(a+v)-f(a)-Tv$ satisfies $\phi'(v) = 0$ which is the desired result.

Comment: yes, the linearity of $g$ depends of the diferentiability of $f$ so $g$ is on $U$. But $\phi^{'}(v) = f^{'}(a+v) - f^{'}(a)$?? because we assume $x = a$.

Comment: No, $\phi$ is a function of $v$ so $\phi'(v) = f'(a+v) -T = 0$.

Comment: so u are applying the theorem of mean value in $\psi$?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$